# How to install NS 2.35 on ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: xorg

I tried to install ns-2.35 on ubuntu 14.04.But I am getting problem like this

```
In file included from /home/mouli/ns-allinone-2.35/tk8.5.10/unix/../generic/tkInt.h:19:0,
                 from /home/mouli/ns-allinone-2.35/tk8.5.10/unix/../generic/tk3d.c:14:
/home/mouli/ns-allinone-2.35/tk8.5.10/unix/../generic/tk.h:76:23: fatal error: X11/Xlib.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make: *** [tk3d.o] Error 1
tk8.5.10 make failed! Exiting ...
For problems with Tcl/Tk see http://www.scriptics.com
mouli@ubuntu:~/ns-allinone-2.35$ ^C
mouli@ubuntu:~/ns-allinone-2.35$
```

Comment: Friends Please give me correct solutions for this question . please quick reply....

Answer (score 1):

You should install `libx11`. Run the following command:

> `sudo apt-get install libx11-dev`

This package provides a client interface to the X Window System, otherwise
known as `Xlib`.  It provides a complete API for the basic functions of the window system.

Comment: @Mouli Reddy If this post answered your question, please mark it as the answer to your question.